# Not able to get Access token in Google Analytics API PHP?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

```
include('GoogleAnalyticsAPI.class.php');

$ga = new GoogleAnalyticsAPI('service');
$ga->auth->setClientId('your_client_id'); // From the APIs console
$ga->auth->setEmail('your_email_addy'); // From the APIs console
$ga->auth->setPrivateKey('/super/secure/path/to/your/privatekey.p12');
$auth = $ga->auth->getAccessToken();
```

i am getting all values in $ga except AccessToken.I have given all paths,email,client id.if i print $auth, nothing is getting displayed.What should i do to get access token?
I refered this site https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried first querying through google analytic query explorer?

Comment: no.what should i do in  google analytic query explorer?